How do I use macvlan to implement VRRP?
I want to implement VRRP on layer 3 switch, but I don't know how to implement it. I have followed these steps to set macvlan, but it still doesn't work. I try to narrow the scope of this issue and I find that the switch0 can't ping to virtual ip address and vice versa.
multilayer switch0 configuration:
Switch#configure t
Switch(config)#in vlan 30
Switch(config-if)#ip addr 192.168.30.29 255.255.255.0
Switch(config-if)#vrrp 30 ip 192.168.30.1
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#in fastEthernet 0/1
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 30

----------------below operations are for macvlan------------------
ip link set vlan30 promisc on
ip link add link vlan30 name vrid30 address 00:00:5e:00:01:1e type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.30.1/24 broadacst 192.168.30.255 dev vrid30
ip link set dev vrid30 up

multilayer switch1 configuration:
Switch#configure t
Switch(config)#in vlan 30
Switch(config-if)#ip addr 192.168.30.69 255.255.255.0
Switch(config-if)#vrrp 30 ip 192.168.30.1
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#in fastEthernet 0/1
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 30

----------------below operations are for macvlan------------------
ip link set vlan30 promisc on
ip link add link vlan30 name vrid30 address 00:00:5e:00:01:1e type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.30.1/24 broadacst 192.168.30.255 dev vrid30
ip link set dev vrid30 up

switch0 configuration:
Switch#configure t
Switch(config)#in vlan 30
Switch(config-if)#ip addr 192.168.30.73 255.255.255.0
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#in fastEthernet 0/1
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 30
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#in fastEthernet 0/2
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 30
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#in fastEthernet 0/3
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 30
Switch(config-if)#exit

topology

I finally solved this issue. The main reason was the packet skb_headroom of macvlan interface was smaller than basic required. Just applied skb_cow to realloc a new headroom for packet to avoid dropping.
